# NavHostFragment: Reopen changed fragment with navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-actionbar

How do I reopen a fragment, that i previously navigated to with the NavHostFragment?

Navigation Drawer:

```
Home => Animals-Fragment
```

Fragments:

```
Animals-Fragment => Bunnies-Fragment => Temporarily change Bunny color to blue from red
```

Navigation Drawer:

```
Bunnies-Fragment => Home
```

Now I want, that when I click on Animals, it shows the Bunnies-Fragment that was altered. This means, I want the already loaded instance of that Fragment. How do I do that?

I'm using following code to swap between Fragments:

```
    NavHostFragment.findNavController(p)
            .navigate(R.id.action_navigation_animals_to_bunniesFragment, bundle);
```

my HomeActivity has this in its onCreate():

```
   AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_animals)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
```

Comment: Does the fragment contains some data to be reopened? If yes, move them to ViewModel. And ViewModel should have activity scope or main graph scope (it means ViewModel should survive even if fragment is destroyed). Then when you reopen the fragment, just show loaded data from ViewModel.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have same problem.

Comment: Sadly no. I wish someone could find one ^^

Answer (score 0):

use popup to instead of the destination

```
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_ThirdFragment_to_FirstFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/FirstFragment" />
```

to understand popup to I recommend you watch this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLfWvSGG5c8

it explains PopUpTo & PopUpToInclusive in such a great way